# Auto Completion with LDAP data is slow

Tags: c#, autocomplete, ldap, ldap-query, ldapconnection

I am using an auto completion property with a text box in C#. The values to be displayed for the suggestions are retrieved from the LDAP directory.

I am using the `FindAll` method to retrieve the data from LDAP.

After I got the `SearchResultCollection` from `FindAll`, I am using it for the first time, I am experiencing a small delay.

This make my suggestion in the autocomplete slow. The `SearchResultCollection` I am getting has a count of 44.

What might be the possible reasons for this delay and how can I overcome that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you specifying a list of attributes to retrieve in your call to `FindAll()` ? If not, the collection might contain all attributes - including stuff like the photo etc - so it might just be very large and therefore sluggish. Try to limit the attributes to be returned (using `DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad`) to those that you **really** need for your situation!

Comment: @marc_s thank you for your reply... but unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue. I am still facing the same issue .